# Why can't MacOS and Windows automatically detect my HP Laser printer?

Tags: macos, printer, window, network-printer, setup

I've had my LaserJet 4000 with a 615N JetDirect for over 20 years now. Once upon a time, I was able to easily connect and print to it from a Mac or Windows machine. I'm not sure if it's something I changed, or something in the OS has changed, but the printer is no longer discoverable.

Setting up the printer was a effortless. You simply added a printer , the OS instantly recognized it, installed the drivers and offered to print a test page. Now, it no longer discoverable. I have to add it as a network printer, type in its assigned hard IP address and locate and install the drivers. If I use a hostname instead of an IP, the OS doesn't resolve it, but oddly enough, the router lists the printer and its hostname on its connected clients list.

I printed out the JetDirect configuration page to see what could be wrong and I noticed an error message:

```
IPX/SPX STATUS: 29
  UNABLE TO SENSE NET NUMBER
MODE:     QUEUE SERVER
NODE NAME:
     NPI768990
IPX/SPX RETRANS:  0
NETWORK FRAME TYPE RCVD
UNKNOWN
```

Pardon the bad formatting, I am displaying it exactly as it appeared on the JetDirect Configuration Page.

What could possibly cause my printer to no longer broadcast its name?  Could it have something to do with the IPX/SPX error?  Could it be my router interfering with it?

Comment: Aside from the answers that were provided, I note that: 1) You can connect to this printer manually (not ideal, but it means you can work); and 2) Apparently it stopped being discoverable recently, on two different OSes. I'd be tempted to say your router is the culprit, either following a firmware update or due to the implementation of new security rules that disable the (aging) IPX/SPX protocol. Have you tried to turn the printer off entirely, shut down the router, turn the printer back on and make sure it's up to speed, then turn the router back on, to foce discovery?

Comment: As an addendum, regarding Windows, Microsoft recently put the lid on some older version of SMB, and IPX/SPX is related to that protocol in the sense that they share the same sub-layer via NetBIOS, which is itself kind of old... This could explain that for Windows. For macOS, as well as for Windows, it could be a simple question of adding/editing a firewall rule, though.

Comment: You're giving me a clue here. You really should add this as an answer.  I do remember something about netbios name last time I researched this issue. Everything works fine, its just not plug and play anymore. I did a reset from the console, but I will try a hard reset.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should ask on retro computing, a lot of ancient knowledge over there and probably someone who knows how to get it broadcasting again.>>>>>>>https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a 4050N with a JetDirect 610N, and aside from some initial driver issues, Windows 10 did discover it okay in 2019. I no longer have Windows 10 here but still use the printer on Linux, via TCP/IP. (Hardware issues with the 610N/615N are discussed at the end of this answer.)

Unless you have a good reason, switch to TCP/IP. It will likely still work 20 years from now, whereas Windows 11 has dropped support for IPX entirely.

In case it helps, my working 4050N network configuration as viewed from its web portal, is

[image]

The host name is normally 'NPI' followed by the last six digits of the network adapter's MAC address, with no spaces.

---

As someone mentioned, the 615N had a known problem with cold solder joints, although if your printer still prints perhaps yours is still functional. HP issued a recall around 15 years ago. A similar issue exists with the 610N, although I believe it was less commonplace.

http://web.archive.org/web/20110609014450/http://www.hp.com/pond/jetdirect/j6057a.html

The issue with solder joints likely related to RoHS and the introduction of lead-free solder - a technology which still had teething problems in the early 2000s. Faulty cards can be brought back to life by reflowing the solder, or even just baking them at sub reflow temperatures. Another old HP user thread illustrates how successful this was.

https://web.archive.org/http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Printers-LaserJet/4200n-network-card-problem-Jetdirect-615n/td-p/1110162#.UoAx_9LP3wM

Similar story with the 610N.

https://web.archive.org/web/20160303192742/http://www.fixyourownprinter.com/forums/laser/47177

---

To those who say "get a new printer" the 4000 series was legendary in terms of durability. My 4050N has done 160,000 pages and still works perfectly after 20 years. It's hard to find something as solid that's this cheap to run. The surplus toner cart market for 4050s is such that, at least in the UK, toner costs a 0.1-0.2p per page.

Comment: Right on!   HP 4000 is a legendary printer. It's older than my first born and still busts out pages like it did on day 1. The resolution is way more than adequate. Anything more than 1200DPI is overkill. It's also fast enough for today's printing needs, since you don't need to print as often.

Answer (score 2):

With an old network card like that, my first suggestion would be to reset it to factory defaults (a cold reset, as HP used to call it). It probably means resetting the entire printer as well.

This [HP support page](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/bpj02738) has general instructions for a cold reset:

> Most HP printers with internal HP Jetdirect print servers can be reset
>   to factory defaults (or cold-reset) by turning the printer off and
>   holding down the ONLINE or GO buttons while turning the printer back
>   on. The printer's control panel display should read Cold Reset or
>   Restoring Factory Settings. If the printer has no LCD display, the
>   indicator lights will cycle.

Answer (score 1):

First off, wow that thing is ancient!  My gut feeling is that is  the problem.

First, older JetDirect cards were known to fail.  I wouldnt say it was common, but it definitely *wasnt* uncommon.  Ive replaced many JetDirect cards in my time.  Secondly, you said the card was a 650N.  As far as I can tell, there was no such model. The 615N was the most common JetDirect card to fail and it was most commonly found in - yep, you guessed it - the 4000 series laser printers.

Next is the error.  IPX/SPX is an old Novell Netware networking protocol.  It really is not something anyone would have been using in the last 20 years.  Your home computers would not be using it.  I dont know why your JetDirect card is complaining about it.  It could just be some kind of misconfiguration.  But I doubt it.

These arent things I have looked at in a *very* long time.  Again, my gut says the JetDirect card has kicked the proverbial bucket.  You can still buy replacement cards.  I checked Amazon, and the cost is basically 1/3 of a new cheap laser printer, so I wouldnt say its cost effective.  Personally, I think you are better off spending your money on a new laser printer, than duct-taping the old one.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, it is a 615N.  I seriously considered prefacing the question with "please do not tell me to upgrade my printer. It works fine thank you.". This printer is bestial!  It was from an era just before the MBAs destroyed HP's brand.  It's fast enough and has numerous add-ons options, like a double sided feeder. The parts and toner are widely available and cheap. The prices on the printers are slowly creeping upwards as more people discover the quality of these machines.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the 615N works fine. It just doesn't broadcast itself like it once did. I think either the router or the OS no longer support whatever protocol it uses for broadcasting the name or the ports are blocked off.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Windows, Microsoft recently put the lid on some older version of SMB, and IPX/SPX is related to that protocol in the sense that they share the same sub-layer via NetBIOS, which is itself kind of old...

This could explain that for Windows. For macOS, as well as for Windows, it could be a simple question of adding/editing a firewall rule, though.